# Discs of minimal area in CAT(0) spaces

Tags: gr.group-theory, gt.geometric-topology, mg.metric-geometry

Let $X$ be a CAT(0) space, $\gamma$ a closed curve in $X$ of length $n$. Let $D$ be a disc with boundary $\gamma$ of smallest possible area. Suppose that the area of $D$ is bigger than $cn^2$ for some constant $c$. Does it follow that $D$ has a flat subdisc with area $ > c'n^2$ for some other constant $c'$  ($n$ is sufficiently large)?

Edit 1: To avoid spaces which are unions of infinitely many larger and larger hyperbolic pieces, assume that $X$ admits a co-compact group action.

Edit 2: In view of Ian Agol's comment, one also needs that the dimension of $X$ is 2.

Comment: It's unclear to me how to put quantifiers to your question...

Comment: $\forall c>0$ $\exists N, c'>0$, $\forall n>N$ $\forall \gamma$ ($(Area (D_\gamma))> cn^2 \to (\exists D' < D: Area(D')> c'n^2$)).

Comment: Then the question whether this holds in every CAT(0) space can be simplified. Indeed, you write a large-scale property but CAT(0) is a homothety invariant. Namely, call minimizing disc that has minimal area among those with the same boundary. Then the question is equivalent to the following one with less quantifiers: is it true that for every CAT(0) space $X$ and every $c>0$ there exists $c'>0$ such that for every minimizing disc with boundary of length 1 and area $\ge c$ contains a flat subdisc of area $>c'$.

Comment: @YCor, in this case, we need to know what 'flat' means, since the hyperbolic plane, say, contains no flat discs. Perhaps Mark wants to restrict to piece wise Euclidean complexes? On the other hand, it should be vacuously true when $c$ is greater than the area of a Euclidean disc of perimeter 1, since there should be no minimal discs whose area is that large.

Comment: @HJRW yes you're right; hopefully the question will eventually be precise.

Comment: Hyperbolic spaces do not have discs with area $cn^2$ for arbitrary $n$.

Comment: @MarkSapir, indeed -- I was responding to Yves's reformulation of your question.  But in any case, the point is that there's an upper bound on the constants $c$ you need to consider.

Comment: This is false without further conditions on $X$ (take a wedge of rescaled hyperbolic planes with scaling constants converging to zero); maybe assume existence of a properly discontinuous cocompact isometric group action.

Comment: The paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/0804.2619.pdf is at least in spirit close to what I am asking.

Comment: I'm still confused by the question. Take a large circle of circumference $n$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$, and perturb it a bit so it's no longer round. Then it bounds an embedded minimal area disc, whose area is close to  $n^2/(4\pi)$ (so bigger than $cn^2$ for some $c$), but which has no flat subdisc (since minimal surfaces are analytic, so contain a flat piece iff flat).

Comment: @Ian: I think this answers my question (I did not know that minimal discs are analytic). Truth, in the case I care about the dimension is 2 (some generalizations of $C(p)-T(q)$ presentations). Do you think there are 2-dimensional examples?

Comment: Not sure. If one takes $c=\frac{1}{4\pi}$, then it seems likely that $D$ must be a flat disc. https://arxiv.org/abs/1611.05261   But if $c<\frac{1}{4\pi}$, I don't see how to prove it.